# Choose all the Reduce function solutions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a simple question that is related to the way to extact and use the values i obtain to plot!

I have a variable A and depending the value the following reduce operation returns 1 or 2 values.

```
A = 0.5;
Reduce[
 {D[-A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 - 0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 1}] == 0,
  D[- A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 - 0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 2}] > 0, 
  2 Pi >= θ > 0}, 
 θ, Reals]

A = 2;
Reduce[
 {D[-A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 - 0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 1}] == 0,
  D[- A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 -0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 2}] > 0, 
  2 Pi >= θ > 0},
 θ, Reals]
```

RETURNS:

```
θ == 3.14159 || θ == 6.28319
θ == 6.28319
```

If i want to plot the result of the reduce operation as function of A, how can i extract the values?

```
Plot[
  Reduce[
    {D[-A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 - 0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 1}] == 0,
     D[- A Cos[θ] + 0.5 Sin[θ]^2 - 0.01 Cos[θ], {θ, 2}] > 0, 
     2 Pi >= θ > 0}, 
    θ, Reals][[2]],
  {A,-20,20}]
```

If i use the `[[2]]` it only will plot the values obtained when there is only one solution. How can I plot all the solutions? 1 when there is only 1 and 2 when there are 2 solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {D[-A Cos[θ] + 1/2 Sin[θ]^2 - 
      1/100 Cos[θ], {θ, 1}] == 0, 
   D[-A Cos[θ] + 1/2 Sin[θ]^2 - 1/100 Cos[θ], {θ, 
      2}] > 0, 2 Pi >= θ > 0};

sol = Reduce[eqn, θ, Reals]

(* (A < 99/100 && θ == π) || (A > -(101/100) && θ == 2 π) *)

funcs = ConditionalExpression[#[[-1, -1]], #[[1]]] & /@
  (sol /. Or :> List)

(* {ConditionalExpression[π, A < 99/100], 
 ConditionalExpression[2 π, A > -(101/100)]} *)

Plot[funcs, {A, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
```

[image]

It is much more straightforward if you use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) with `Method->Reduce`

```
sol2 = Solve[eqn, θ, Reals, Method -> Reduce]

(* {{θ -> ConditionalExpression[π, A < 99/100]}, {θ -> 
   ConditionalExpression[2 π, A > -(101/100)]}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[θ /. sol2], {A, -20, 20},
 PlotRange -> {0, 7}]
(* same picture *)
```